# How can I automatically run a vim script whenever I change source file within vim?

Tags: vim

I wrote a (perl) script that generates a syntax highlight vim script (tags.vim) from the tags file (generated by ctags). However, when I open a file I have to manually load it. I can fix that by starting vim with the right command line, but once inside vim every time I switch source file (for example by pressing ^] to jump to a definition in another file) the syntax highlighting is lost and I need to re-source my generated tags.vim.

Is there a way to execute a command (:so tags.vim) or source a script etc, automatically whenever the current source file changes (by :n, :N, ^] or :tnext etc.)?

Comment: This might be an XY problem. What kind of highlights do you generate, and how? If you're using `:highlight`, which is Vim-global, it might make more sense to change the syntax definition for your filetype (or make a custom filetype for your custom syntax). This way, your syntax definition (and consequently highlights) are buffer-local, and would persist across buffer switching...

Comment: @Amadan What I said, I generate highlighting from a ctags file; so, my own namespace, classes, structs, functions, enums, etc. Those vary from project to project so it isn't something you want to put in your ~/.vim/syntax directory. If I'd ever open two windows to different projects at the same time then really they should source different tags.vim files.

Answer (score 4):

This is what autocommands are for, see `:h autocommand`

In this case you're likely to want the BufEnter autocommand, triggered whenever vim goes to a different file (`:h BufEnter`). Probably something like this:

```
augroup UpdatePerlSyntax  " :h autocmd-group
    autocmd!  " Clear autocommands for this group - prevents defining the same
              " autocommand multiple times
    autocmd BufEnter * source /path/to/tags.vim  " Or whatever action you want
    "       |        | |
    "       |        | +- Command to execute
    "       |        +- Pattern (:h autocmd-patterns), * matches everything
    "       +- :h autocmd-events
augroup END
```

In addition to BufEnter, there is the `FileType` autocommand, which might suit you needs a bit better (`:h filetype`).

In order to use the name of the current file in the autocommand, look at `:h <afile>`

---

Another (possibly more elegant) solution is to write a syntax file for the filetypes you are concerned with that uses the generated syntax `(:h mysyntaxfile)`.

Comment: It's taken me longer than I thought; but I intend to accept your answer as soon as I actually used it - I'm still wrestling with the syntax files themselves, so this can take a while :/. Just wanted to add a comment showing that I didn't forget this ;). I'm working on it like full time!

Comment: +1 For me, the `:h mysyntaxfile` and `after/syntax/c.vim` was the way to do it. Project-specific syntax needs `set runtimepath+=./after` in `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

In [lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags/), I update tag database on the autocommands  [`BufWritePost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufWritePost)
 and [`FileWritePost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#FileWritePost). On the way I update the syntax highlighting for the current buffer.

What I should also do (but did completely forgot), is to update the highlighting in the buffers already opened. But beware, this highlighting update shall not be done every time we enter a buffer ([`:h BufEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufEnter)), but only if it hasn't already been done. IOW, if you source a file, you'll need to [check its timestamp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/lh-vim-lib.txt#L1004) ([`:h getftime()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getftime%28%29))

Indeed, I benched the syntax updating when the ctags database is updated. The slower part isn't the fetching of all the tags, but the actual call to `syn keyword` (which is the fastest of the lot), 100,000 times (on a real project).